# SQL - Select ALL rows that are LIKE%...% of each other (All Similar Rows)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example, lets say in column `source` I have the following entries

```
SourceFileEmbed122
SourceFile1333
SourceItem13366
PreLoadSource7755
```

And I do a query of `SourceFile` it should match row 1 and 2 and show me all the column data for that row, but if I search for example: `PreLoadSource` or `SourceItem` it shouldnt show anything, as there is only 1 row that has a similar entry.

Kinda like an if contains sort of thing.

Basically, I want to do something like:
`SELECT source, COUNT(*) TotalCount FROM sources GROUP BY source HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

But the query does LIKE instead of LIKE%...% (Like in PHPMyAdmin) which results in it only matching EXACT matches of each other, so stuff like:

```
row123/
row123
```

Wont match each other and will be ignored. But I want this to MATCH basically if row123's full text is ALSO all in another row's value, then match.

Lets say I have:

```
http://link.ext/dir123/file.mp3
http://link.ext/dir123
http://link.ext/dir123/file2.mp3
http://link.ext/dir123
```

The query should match `.../file.mp3`, `.../file2.mp3` and `../dir123` because row 2 `http://link.ext/dir123` is also in row 1, 3 and 4.

Comment: did you mean it will show only the rows if there are more than 1 match?

Comment: Is this really a question about the existence of AND and OR in sql queries ? I hope I am misunderstanding.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar Yes show if there are more than 2 and if its basically "contains" the source, Like basically im just looking to get a duplicate checker but a bit more better as some rows in my db are a bit complex but result in the exact same item.

Comment: ... `HAVING COUNT(source) > 1);`

Comment: I updated my question explaining it a lot more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is doing a inner join with the same table,
if you need a simple count you can do something like that:

```
SELECT s1.source, COUNT(*)
FROM sources s1
INNER JOIN sources s2
    ON s1.id <> s2.id AND s1.source LIKE CONCAT('%', s2.source, '%')
GROUP BY s1.source
```

Comment: at the start you have a spelling mistake, but it works for exactly what I need, thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to test for at least two matches is:

```
select s.*
from sources s
where s.source like '%<whatever>%' and
      exists (select 1
              from source s2
              where s2.source like '%<whatever>%' and
                    s2.source <> s.source
             );
```